# how to read the content of file and store it in formatted array in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to read text from file, checking its content and then storing it in an array of string.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathToFiles, FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

do{

      line=sr.ReadLine();
      if (line == "databases")
       {
           j = 0;
           while ((ch = sr.Read()) != '}')
           {
               admin_databases[j] = sr.ReadLine();
               j++;
           }
       }
       else if (line == "table_name")
       {

           j = 0;
           while ((ch = sr.Read()) != '}')
           {
               admin_table_name[j] = sr.ReadLine();
               j++;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           Response.Write(line+" ");
       }
} while (line !=null);
```

The text is read by using ReadLine() method, but while checking its content 
i.e

```
if(line=="databases")
```

it shows null string and hence unable to store it in an array.
what is the mistake that i am making here?

Comment: Maybe something related to whitespaces / carriage returns ? Don't hesitate to use debugger and provide us sample file...

Comment: is there any method to overcome from the problem of whitespaces?

Comment: You said "line" is null ? Did you get the first lines before this happens ? Are you sure your file is not empty ? (if you write it just before the read, are you sure you didn't miss a Close() ?)

Comment: @Richard I think that variable 'line' is null because of which it is unable to compare with strings like "databases"/"table_name"..problem is the control is directly jumping to the else part and displaying the output on webpage which is correct

Comment: @Richard plz help..i think you are  the only last hope

Comment: in your own code, "line" is the result of what has been read in the file, and it has nothing to do with the comparisons you do under. "line" will only be equal to null at the end of loop (end of file), but before it will be set with file content. So : does the "Response.Write" produces anything ?

Comment: yes,Response.Write() is displaying the content of file correctly.which means that line variable has something stored in it..so if there is content in line then why it is not getting compared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to last comments under main post :

According to what you say, we're back to whitespace theory !

A few tips :

- Replace Response.Write(line+" "); by Response.Write("'" + line+"'"); just to see exact captured values.
- Check your file content.
- You could also replace your == operators by more specific comparisons : String.Compare with case insensitive param, or String.StartsWith() / Contains(), etc, rather than exact comparison.
- You could also clean up your input string with "Trim()", etc.

Comment: Thank you so much.Actually,the problem was with Whitespaces.I have used String.Compare() method and problem got solve..thank you once again. Keep helping like this in future.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but we don't know what is in your file. Maybe problem is in any whitespaces.

In this line of code:

```
while ((ch = sr.Read()) != '}')
```

You missed one '='. It should look like that:

```
while ((ch == sr.Read()) != '}')
```

Comment: That's wrong. Setting a variable and comparing it on same line are common practices for input reading. And also, OP's problem seems to happen before this line...

Comment: @Perk Original Poster. In this case, you!

Comment: @Richard is there any method to overcome from the problem of whitespaces?